# How to use KVC with NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, kvc

I am trying to make an example for KVC in objectiv-c, I am using an online compiler for objective-c.

I wrote the code posted below, and when i compile it, i receive the following error:

```
 jdoodle.m:7:5: warning: 'NSString' may not respond to '-alloc'
 [[str alloc] init];
```

please let me know how to fix it

**code**:

```
NSString *str;
[[str alloc] init];

[[str setValue:@"value-str"] forKey:@"key-str"];
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with KVC?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the syntax replace

`[[str alloc] init]` by `str = [[NSString alloc] init]`

`[[str setValue:@"value-str"] forKey:@"key-str"]` by `[str setValue:@"value-str" forKey:@"key-str"]`

Read [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1).

`[str setValue:@"value-str" forKey:@"key-str"]` is not going to work. The `NSString` class doesn't have a property `key-str`.